# excel/google sheet - arrayformula for cooking planner

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup

so i make this "cooking planner" by using 2 resource data (recipes, and cooking planning),
the "recipes" (cell A:C) data row will be added continuously whenever i have a new recipes.

therefore the recipes in "cooking planning" (cell E:M) data row will be added automatically too according the "recipes" data (in cell A:C)

then i have this "ingredient requirement" cell (cell E10:M16)  that will count all the ingredient of the recipes combined (currently using vlookup)

but whenever i add a new recipes, i have to edit the old vlookup formula (adding a new recipes) and the formula gotten too long.

can it be done using arrayformula or any shorter formula?

thank you before.

google sheet link :
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15mP1q_Qia-CADqqn7mzbKwIS5YrGv4W4iqyUEpqfVWY/edit?usp=sharing

i tried using vlookup formula, but whenever i added a new recipes, i must add new vlookup formula for each recipes.

can it be done using arrayformula where it will add automatically when i added new recipes?

Comment: I would put the data on a separate sheet, and as you know which column is which you can omit the headings. Then the vlookup() will reference the columns on the data sheet and the table_array can be data_sheet!A:Z or whatever you name the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I've added a solution [in a new tab](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15mP1q_Qia-CADqqn7mzbKwIS5YrGv4W4iqyUEpqfVWY/edit#gid=784540611). please do test it out and lemme know of any misses.

- cells with blue have formulas accommodated.

[image]

Comment: wow! it worked exactly, thanks alot! will use and test it with any conditions

Comment: in 'ingredient requirement' formula, how can i add more source from another recipes tables (i tried the sum but it shows error)..

Comment: updated the formulas. can you check on it.